# Assign a group from logged in user contact group to new individual

Tags: extension, groups, postcode

I am trying to assign a group from currently logged in user(One group in assigned only) to a newly created individual.

```
function search_civicrm_post($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef){ {

$getContactId = (int) CRM_Core_Session::singleton()->getLoggedInContactID();

try {
    $result = civicrm_api3('GroupContact', 'getsingle', [
        'return' => ["group_id"],
        'contact_id' => $getContactId,
    ]);
} 
catch (CRM_Exception $e) {
    echo "error";
}

$getGroupId = $result['group_id'];
$recentContactId= '';
$query ="INSERT INTO `civicrm_group_contact` (`group_id`, `contact_id`, `status`) VALUES ('.$getGroupId', '$recentContactId','Added')";
```

But problem is that how will I get the id of recently added individuals;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you want to add contact (New individual) to a group of  logged in user, then i would write something like this

```
function search_civicrm_pre($op, $objectName, $id, &$params) {
  if ($objectName == 'Individual' && $op == 'create) {
    $groups = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'getsingle', [
      'return' => "group",
      'id' => 'user_contact_id',
    ])['groups'];
    foreach (explode(',', $groups) as $groupId) {
      $params['group'][$groupId] = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Hello Pradip Sir, I successfully fetch the group id of currently logged in contact(Only one group is there). When I am adding a new Individual it must attach a group of currently logged in contact. How can I do that? I am not getting a solution.

Comment: Did you try above snippet?

Comment: Yes. Give an error "field group unset or not existing"

Comment: That means the logged in user is not assigned to any group

Comment: Use TRY CATCH method to handle fatal error when Logged in user is not assigned to any group

Comment: No Sir. It is already in there (I checked by GroupContact API) and also showing a group id.

Comment: What does contact api with above params return?

Comment: {


    "invalid_field": "group",
    "is_error": 1,
    "error_message": "field group unset or not existing"
}

Comment: I used a groupcontact API and it will return a group ID. But I want to add it to the new Individual contact.

Comment: I have updated the code, Try the updated snippet

Comment: Thanks Pradeep Sir. It is working very well. But how this code is working. I didn't understand.

Comment: pre() hook is used to alter the params which is used for creating a contact. You can pass additional params likes groups, tags etc since the BAO handles it correctly. In short pre() hook is invoked just before a contact is created and post after a contact.